# Does __autoload affect included files?

Tags: php, autoload

I have index.php file where on the very top I define __autoload magic function.

```
function __autoload($className) {
   echo "autoloading $className";
   require_once('application/models/'.strtolower($className).'.php');
}
```

Then, I reference to the User object that is included by __autoload automatically (User.php). Everything works fine until this moment.
The problem is that User.php references to the File class

```
        $obj->numberOfUploads = File::countUploadsByUser($obj->ID);
```

and at this point the error is thrown

> Fatal error: Class 'File' not found in Z:\home\project\www\application\models\user.php on line 19

The thing is, that i can see the output

> autoloading User

but cannot see anything regarging the File. So, as it seems, the __autoload function is not called at all when the reference to File is caught. Tryting to add __autoload function to the User.php resulted in an error about redeclaring the function.

I am sorry if the question was raised before, I tried to google it and found no information.

Cheers

Comment: I think it's possible that the output you're seeing is a false positive, as you're probably seeing when the `User` script was loaded. I'm just starting to learn how to use namespaces, but I wonder if that would help with this issue? http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: You were right - the output is shown ONLY in case the include was successful. I have not dealt with namespaces yet as this is a relatively new feature, so I cannot say whether it can help or not. But Fabian Tamp solution does the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments on [autoload in the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) it seems like a number of people have had similar problems when it comes to defining `__autoload` twice.

I would recommend using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) with an anonymous function to avoid multiple definition conflicts, as illustrated in example 1 of that page:

```
// Or, using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

Also, you don't need to use `require_once` (can just use `require`) because if the class is already found, the handler won't be called again.

Try using `spl_autoload_register` just in your `index.php` file, and if that doesn't work, put one in your `User.php` as well.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is not about redefining the function. I am trying to understand whether __autoload will work in files it included or not. I mean, if not then this is more likely to be a PHP bug

Comment: I thought about that too... it *should* work in included files, because "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward" (see [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: the person who wrote [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#104282) seemed to have a similar problem to you.

Comment: I tried the code you provided and it works like a charm. There is no need to include it in any other files that index.php as this function works exactly as expected - every loaded page uses spl_autoload when referencing to the undeclared class. Brilliant, thank you! It still confuses me why __autoload would not work though

Comment: Great! Glad that helped. Not a problem! I learnt heaps from your question :)

Comment: Good to hear it helped both of us :-)